# solution for $\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left ( \frac{1}{1+e^{n} } \right )$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a closed form for $$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left ( \frac{1}{1+e^{n} } \right )?$$

I'm looking for the solution of $$\prod_{n=1}^{N}\left (1-\left ( \frac{1}{1+e^{-n} } \right )\right )$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you familiar with the 1-Pochhammer symbol?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{p} \left\{ 1 - \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-n}}\right) \right\} &= \frac{1}{\prod_{n=1}^{p} \left\{ 1 - e^{n} \right\}} 
= \frac{1}{(e;e)_{p}} 
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
(a; q)_{n} = \prod_{k=0}^{p-1} \left( 1 - a \, q^{k-1} \right) 
\end{align}
is the q-Pochhammer notation defined in [Wkik q-Pochhammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol#q-series).

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot.